# Can Allah make another God

Tags: quran, allah, kufr

Many verses in the Quran state that Allah can do everything. The thing is, I don't know if Allah can make another God that's greater than Allah.

So my question is: **is it kufr to think that Allah can't make another God greater than him ? Or can Allah actually make a God that's greater than him ?**

Comment: Why shouldn't HE be able to do so?

Comment: Where do these ideas come from guys? :) Yes Allah is capable of everything, but he doesn't want everything. I don't think Allah will "create" some creature and make it greater than him.  "He is the First and **the Last**, the Most High and Most Near,1 and He has ˹perfect˺ knowledge of all things." [https://quran.com/57/3](https://quran.com/57/3).

Comment: This question is just like the question “can Allah create a rock He himself cannot lift”? It’s baseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allah S.W.T can do everything, but He will not do something that does not befit Him, or goes against His Attributes. It is like asking if Allah can have a son. Or even more absurdly, can Allah be God and not be God?

The question is essentially invalid at first place. A God by definition is the creator of everything. So if something is created, then it can't be God. And if a "god" does something which goes against his attributes, then it ceases to be "god". So, the question "Can Allah make another God?" has a contradiction, hence meaningless.

It is certainly a kufr thought to think of, but kufr doesn't apply to the person for just having the mere thought...

> It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that some people from amongst the Companions of the Apostle (may peace be upon him) came to
> him and said: Verily we perceive in our minds that which every one of
> us considers it too grave to express. He (the Holy Prophet) said: Do
> you really perceive it? They said: Yes. Upon this he remarked: That is
> the faith manifest.
>
> Book: The Book of Faith - كتاب الإيمان,
> Global Id: 10355 (0) English reference: Book 1, Hadith 239

This indicates that if someone gets a kufr thought but resists it and drives it way, then it is a sign of faith. It is only an act of kufr if someone actually believes in those thoughts. The best thing to do is to not continue thinking about these thoughts when they come up, especially that they are invalid.

Comment: Other things you mentioned are possible but Allah can't create another God. I mean one of the attribute of God is being uncreated. So you can't create uncreated being.

Answer (score 1):

Allah can do whatever he want to do.
But Allah will not do something which is not fitting with his attributes.
For Example: If someone ask if Allah can sleep or If he can eat?.
They are not fitting with the attributes of Almighty Allah.
So, Definitely "NO".

Answer (score 0):

The power [qudrah] of Allāh does not relate to impossibilities [muhāl], only to those things which are possible.

It is impossible that there be another god, and so the power of Allāh does not relate to this.

Answer (score 0):

Allah is "Al-Qadeer" All Powerful. He can create anything and everything. This question has its own answer. If a Creator is creating something, then it will be "His creation" not "all powerful" or Nauzobillah powerful than Him, because the one who cannot create himself, will not be a god, but just another creation of God (Allah), like Human beings, Angels, Jinn etc. This is clearly explained in Surah Ikhlas.  We are all creations of Allah and cannot create anything on our own. So that creation cannot be credited as "God". Allah says in Surah Hajj Ayat 73: "O humanity! A lesson is set forth, so listen to it ˹carefully˺: those ˹idols˺ you invoke besides Allah can never create ˹so much as˺ a fly, even if they ˹all˺ were to come together for that. And if a fly were to snatch anything away from them, they cannot ˹even˺ retrieve it from the fly. How powerless are those who invoke and those invoked!" So His creations are so powerless. The god He will create will be equally powerless. When Iblees asked for power from Him, He gave him power, but How powerless Iblees is, we all know.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Allah is able to elevate one to the level of Godhood, or create a God, or elevate one to His Level, to be His Equal. In this case, such a person would occupy the rank of being the Entrusted Servant of Allah, Entrusted with Monotheism, Entrusted with keeping the Oneness of Allah intact. To be entrusted with Tawheed means that Allah will trust this person to never disobey Him.

The shahaadah: "There is no god worthy of worship except Allah".
This statement does not negate the possibility of there being other gods, but rather points towards the exclusivity of Allah's worthiness of worship. Allah is the only God that is worthy of worship, even if there are any other gods.
He has fashioned mankind exactly in His Image, because He wanted them to join Him and be with Him in His realm, the realm of ascension, عالم الاستواء. If you want this, all you need to do is ask Him, and He will accept your request. That is the Kingdom of Allah.